# Can I develop background applications?

Tags: amazon-fire-tv

I know the Amazon Fire TV device runs a derivate of Android OS. Although I have no experience of it, I know I can develop applications that run in the background for Android OS.

But is it possible to develop always-running, background applications for the Amazon Fire TV device? I couldn't find any information in the limited documentation on the Amazon website, it only talks about games and foreground applications...

Comment: what would you have running as a background service on a TV connected device? In theory you could have a background (or foreground) service running within the constraints of garbage collection though it would presumably need a UI as well for the user to install/interact with (eg something like Pandora that plays music which you navigate would be a service)

Comment: The idea is that it's an always on device which means i van use it for things like home automation that doesn't require a up but instead an always running service

Comment: you can have services running, and they can communicate over IP so should work (memory pressure is the only thing to watch out for as the foreground app will always win)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal - when you mean memory pressure, will the OS actually shut my service down if it runs about of memory?

Comment: yup, standard Android behavior... foreground apps take priority and services get shut down if needed to keep them running